# When accessing https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/{id}/recipients forbidden error is displayed

Tags: twilio, sendgrid

I am trying to access the sendgrid Rest API using GET https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/lists/xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx/recipients to get contacts from contacts list

I have also provided headers to rest api call

```
Content-Type: application/json   
Authorization: Bearer SG.xxxxx
```

Below is the error shown

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "field": null,
      "message": "access forbidden"
    }
  ]
}
```

The documentation for above rest URL is https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/contacts-api-lists/retrieve-all-recipients-on-a-list

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you make sure that the access token you generated in sendgrid has access to the contacts? I believe there is a specific check box to be able to access contacts.

Comment: No issue with authentication

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the sendgrid support team for the issue. The rest api mentioned above in question is for legacy users and not for new user.

legacy users => contactdb api

new users => marketing api